# How to update Xamarin Project template (nuget version) in visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Whenever I create Xamarin.Forms application it comes with old versions of Xamarin Forms nuget. I have to update all packages by hand for each solution.

Is there a way to update the templates in Visual Studio so I can eliminate that update step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to change the Project Templates from Xamarin, so that you cand target a specific `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet.

*I don't think its a good idea because you will need to do a lot of changes manually and it could lead to errors. Plus i don't know what will happen when Xamarin update the Project templates.*

First you will have to find the location of the template.
In my computer (windows) is located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\4.0.3.214\T\PT\Cross-Platform\Xamarin.Forms.PCL.zip
```

Open the zip (I've tested it with 7z). 
Inside folder we have all the templates for the generated projects from a `Xamarin.Forms` Project. (*FormsTemplate, FormsTemplate.Droid, FormsTemplate.iOS, FormsTemplate.UWP, FormsTemplate.Windows, FormsTemplate.WindowsPhone*).

For each of this folder you will have to open the folder and find a file with extension `"*.vstemplate"`. This file have the configuration for each Xamarin.Forms sub-project.

Inside of each `"*.vstemplate"` you will find this:

```
  <WizardData>
    <packages repository="extension" repositoryId="Xamarin.VisualStudio">
      <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.0.0.6482" />
    </packages>   
  </WizardData>
```

You will have to replace the `version="2.0.0.6482"` to your preferred version.

**You will have to do this for every sub-project.**

Now is mandatory that you have the selected version of `Xamarin.Forms` Nuget downloaded into you machine.

My folder is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\4.0.3.214\Packages`

Go to the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/) website, download the `Xamarin.Forms` package and place it in `Packages` folder (the downloaded package is lower case, you must rename to match the package name in `<WizardData> <packages>`).

Hopefully i helped you.

Sources: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx)

---

## A simpler solution (Update all projects at the same time)

**Right click** in your **Solution** then go to **Manage NuGet Packages For Solution**.

It will open the **Nuget Package Manager** and from there you can select to update the Nuget for all or any selected Project.

[image]

Comment: My guestion was how to update the templates so I wouldn't have to update per solution.  Creating new fresh forms application still leaves me with old version of xamarin forms.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the answer will full explanation.

Comment: @jzeferino, you are saying that you're not recommending this manual solution. In that case, what is the recommended solution? Updating NuGet packages after the creation of the solution is different from creating the solution with the latest package version. For example, [this](https://readerman1.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/xamarin-build-action-embeddedresource-is-not-supported-by-one-or-more-of-the-projects-targets/) bug makes updating Forms packages very painful and troublesome.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze I recommend update them manually if you are in Xamarin Studio (there will be a new version of it with a better Package Manager), but if you are in Visual studio you can use the Package Manager to update all specific Nuget in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You also can go Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery or Product Updates.

Hope that can solve your problems.